# Enable Remote unlock from the Settings via ADB (no root)

Tags: adb, samsung, security, settings, remote-control

I am trying to enable the Setting "Remote unlock" from Samsung *(in Settings -> Biometrics and security -> Find My Mobile -> Remote unlock)* by using the adb.

I could enable other settings like Bluetooth or WiFi by using some commands on the adb. Now, I am trying to figure out how to enable this "Remote unlock" by Samsung. I searched all the Android documents and references but couldn't find any solutions. I personally gave up and I don't believe this is even possible.

I wrote `adb shell settings put secure fmm_unlock_recovery 1` and it seems to work. The only problem is, my devices don't connect to the internet because of too many failed password attempts.

Could someone tell me how or just if it's possible to enable it just by adb?

Comment: scrcpy wont help me in this case sadly. My device suddenly dont accept my 3 years pattern lock, so i have to enable the "remote unlock" via adb to change my pattern with "find my mobile samsumg". But it needs the setting "remote unlock" enable which is not the case sadly

Comment: if phone *suddenly* deny unlock pattern, reboot is recommended. on the other hand, reboot is **not** recommended on *secure startup* enabled devices as you might lose the availbility to connect internet in case unlock is still denied

Comment: So this explains why i cant access to the internet anymore and why i cant reset my password via "find my device" from google...

Comment: No, I mislead you. [secure startup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61428806) would effect adb, too. Your question still applies

Comment: guess something like *'adb shell settings put blobal ...'* https://dev.to/larsonzhong/most-complete-adb-commands-4pcg

Comment: yes the problem is i cant find the location for the Android Packages/Paramaters for the "Remote Unlock" that enables it (what after the "adb shell settings put" comes. I searched the whole  Android Documents and couldnt find it

Comment: can't you insert SIM card with mobile data?

Comment: I tried this but it did not work, i think the device has to be unlocked once after reboot to have access to the internet because a android Notification tells me to first unlock the phone to get app-notifications.

Comment: searched for your last comment, sounds like a feature for (FBE) encrypted devices called Strong protection, seems some kind of successor to (FDE) Secure startup. you might figure out the adb command for *Settings>Biometrics and security>Other security settings>Strong protection*

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried to disable "Strong protection" but i couldnt.I will try to figure it again but if i cant, i will just factory reset my device, because i am so desperated and dont think i will able to do it. But really, thank u for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Setting-Parameters are for enabling "Find my Mobile":

```
fmm_community_finding=1
fmm_pub_tag_finding=0
fmm_unknown_tag_alert=0
fmm_unlock_recovery=1
```

So by writing the following commands, you can enable the Samsung's Find My Mobile via adb:

```
adb shell settings put secure fmm_community_finding 1
adb shell settings put secure fmm_pub_tag_finding 0
adb shell settings put secure fmm_unknown_tag_alert 0
adb shell settings put secure fmm_unlock_recovery 1
```

Keep in mind that you have to reboot "adb reboot" after writing these commands!